# Proto DataStore not working on apple silicon

Tags: android, android-studio, protocol-buffers, android-jetpack, endpoints-proto-datastore

getting error when i run my code in Android Studio Canary 15

> Execution failed for task ':app:generateInappProto'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:protobufToolsLocator_protoc'.
> Could not find protoc-3.17.0-osx-aarch_64.exe (com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.0).
> Searched in the following locations: